# Are there existing ground vehicles in the Faith RPG?

Tags: vehicles, faith-the-scifi-rpg

Faith's developers went out of business before completing all their goals for the RPG, unfortunately, so there are holes in places.  There are *rules* for ground vehicles in the core rulebook, a space vehicle module that carries ground vehicles (that my players have), and mentions in the lore section about ground vehicles being a major deal on a specific planet (that my players are on).  But no stats for them anywhere that I can find.  However, one of the main draws (no pun intended) of Faith is also one of the main drawbacks - many statblocks are only found on cards in decks that are no longer being manufactured, making them expensive and difficult to acquire, and with no electronic counterpart, no way for me to search to determine which deck to buy, if any.

Hence my question.  I'd prefer "official" ground vehicles if they exist, I'll buy the deck they're in if you can just give me the name;  barring that, if there's an online resource you can recommend with fan-created vehicles, I'll take that.  If I had more experience with the system or some kind of starting point, I could homebrew my own, but neither of those conditions are true at the moment.  Bonus points if wherever you can point me has any of the following:  modules for ground vehicles, more ships, or more ship modules.  Thanks.

(I have the deck that comes in the Garden In Hell box set, Tools of the Trade I, and Nefarious Folk.  They're definitely not in any of those.)